# Div moves to left on failed validation because of the validation message

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs : One has a Login form(with `float:left`) and the other has the Registration form(with `float:right`) in my aspx page.

I have put `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator... />` on the `<asp:TextBox.../>` of both the forms. The Login form(on **left**) works fine on validation, but the Registration form(on **right**) moves to left because the validation message inserted on failed validation and then pushes the complete div more to the **left.**

What is the solution to stop that..?

ASPX :

```
 <div class="row" style="min-height: 500px">
            <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 70px; float: left">
                <h2 class="form-login-heading" style="font-weight: 400">Sign In Now</h2>
                <div class="login-wrap">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUname" runat="server" CssClass="span3" placeholder="Email or Phone Number" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqUsername" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidateLogin" ControlToValidate="txtUname" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please Enter a Username!" Display="Dynamic" /><br />

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" CssClass="span3" placeholder="Password" TextMode="password" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqPass" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidateLogin" ControlToValidate="txtPass" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please Enter a Password!" Display="Dynamic" /><br />

                    <button runat="server" id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-1 btn-1a" title="signin" validationgroup="ValidateLogin" style="margin-left: 50px" onserverclick="btnLogin_ServerClick">
                        <i class="icon-unlock"></i>SIGN IN
                    </button>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessge" runat="server" CssClass="registration" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" />
                    <br />
                    <div class="registration">
                        Don't have an account yet?<br />
                        <a class="" href="Registration.aspx">Create an account
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <!-- Second Div -->

    <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-right: 170px; float: right">
                <h2 class="form-login-heading" style="font-weight: 400">Register!</h2>
                <div class="login-wrap">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="span3" placeholder="Name" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="ValidateReg" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="What will We call You?" Display="Dynamic" /><br />

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="span3" placeholder="Email" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ValidationGroup="ValidateReg" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="This will be used as your Username!" Display="Dynamic" /><br />

                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRegister" class="btn btn-1 btn-1a" ValidationGroup="ValidateReg" Text="SIGN UP" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

I tried to change the `margin-left` property too, but nothing seems to work.

**NOTE :**  I also need a nice stylish vertical divider between the two divs. Any ideas for that too are welcome ..!

I want something like this  : http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/85dV6/show/

**UPDATE :** i have added this class :

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right: 1px solid red; height: 400px; width: 400px;">
            <div style="height: 30px; width: 30px; border: 1px solid red; border-radius: 50%; font-weight: bold; line-height: 28px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; float: right; position: absolute; right: -16px; top: 40%; z-index: 1; background: #DFDFDF;">
                OR
            </div>
        </div>
```

The output is this  :

[image: The <code>OR</code> gets shifted to the right and <code>vertical divider</code> to the left]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this css with your registration form...

```
float:right!important;  insted of float:right;
```

For the divider you can use `<hr>` or stick with the divider class of twitter bootstrap and add some additional css of yours.

**Update**: the divider you [Want](https://jsfiddle.net/76ukxw3v/)

Comment: i am using inline CSS , i dont know why it doesent work somehow!

Comment: I managed to handle the movement of the div , but i want the divider to be something like this  : http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/85dV6/show/

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted.. i copied your CSS and pasted it `inline` , i dont know why the CSS gets spoilt and the div boxes get disorganized and even the `OR` text doesnt show up ! i am adding a screenshot for u too see !

Comment: try to use the css as external or internal instead of in-line